# Save the pdf using the selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to save the pdf open on clicking. According to my, using the selenium webdriver the code works automatically. I want the pdf open should be saved automatically through code using selenium in python. Please assist for the below code to save the pdf in the folder.

```
enter code here
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time
url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 
    20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search- 
    pro-details']//a[contains(.,'Search Project Details')]"))).click()
Registered_Project_radio= WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Promoter")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Registered_Project_radio)
Application = driver.find_element_by_id("CertiNo")
Application.send_keys("P50500000005")
Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 
    10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnSearch")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Search)
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in 
      driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") if
      item.get_attribute('href') is not None]

View = View[0]
request = urllib.request.Request(View)
btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 
     20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
     "//a[@class='btn btn-md btn-success' and @id='btnShow_2017']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)
```

Comment: usually in web browser you can set what to do with different type of file - download or open with some external program. It should be somewhere in options.  In some question I saw how to set it with webdriver using `ChromeOptions` or `ChromeProfile`.

Comment: if you can get `href` to this file then you could try to use `urllib` or `requests` to download it.

Comment: it seems it adds `<object data=...>` which has PDF encoded `base64` in `data=`

Comment: It shows the pop up window after clicking the button.

Comment: what is in this pop up window ? Is this window displaying PDF ? It seems page uses `<object data=...>` to display PDF and all PDF is in `data=` encoded `base64`.

Comment: I does'nt contain the href link.

Comment: Yes the pop window displaying the pdf. But it doesn't have href.

Comment: it doesn't have href because it has all PDF as text (encoded `base64`) directly in `data=`

Comment: @furas: I have posted the question related to your answer.  But it is unable to download the pdf .Can you please check the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158681/download-the-file-which-has-stream-url-is-the-chrome-extension-in-the-embed-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking it adds `<object data="application/pdf;base64,...">` which has all PDF as text encoded bas64 in `data=`

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)

time.sleep(5)

# get tag <object>
obj = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('object')

# get `data=`
data = obj.get_attribute('data')

# get text after `base64,`
text = data.split(',')[1]

# encode text to PDF's content (as bytes)
import base64
bytes = base64.b64decode(text)

# save bytes in file
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes)
```

And now you have all in `output.pdf`

Tested of Firefox

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

url = 'https://maharerait.mahaonline.gov.in'
#chrome_path = r'C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/Scripts/chromedriver.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()#executable_path=chrome_path)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='search-pro-details']//a[contains(.,'Search Project Details')]"))).click()
Registered_Project_radio = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Promoter")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",Registered_Project_radio)

Application = driver.find_element_by_id("CertiNo")
Application.send_keys("P50500000005")

Search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"btnSearch")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Search)
View = [item.get_attribute('href') for item in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a") if item.get_attribute('href') is not None]

btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 
     20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
     "//a[@class='btn btn-md btn-success' and @id='btnShow_2017']")))

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",btn)

time.sleep(5)

obj = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('object')
data = obj.get_attribute('data')
text = data.split(',')[1]

import base64
bytes = base64.b64decode(text)

with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes)
```

Comment: @furas- I have posted the question related to your answer. But it is unable to download the pdf. Can you please check the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158681/download-the-file-which-has-stream-url-is-the-chrome-extension-in-the-embed-tag