# How to split the sublist from the list and add the data in another list

Tags: python, pandas

[image: input in which the latitude column needs to be splited]

I need to create one more dataframe which has the column format

```
df_codata["Latlong"]=  [{"__type":"GeoPoint","latitude":x,"longitude":y}]
```

As seen in the image the "Latlong" contains the "latitude" which has sublist. I need to create dataframe which give me output such as for the single "C_ID" it has multiple sublist of "latitude" I want to add to add sublist first number in "latitude" of df_codata dataframe and second number of the sublist in "longitude" of dataframe. Want the desired output attached below:
[image: Desired output]
Kindly suggest for the issue. I am unable to split the sublist and insert it two subcolumns of "latitude" and "longitude"

Comment: Please suggest for the above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do some kind of data preprocessing to get your desired output. Here is one of the possible solutions to solve your task:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

def extend_coordinates(coordinates, c_id, geo_type):
    result = []
    for elem in coordinates:
        if len(elem) == 2:
            # normal case
            latitude, longitude = elem
        else:
            latitude, longitude = [None, None]
        result.append([c_id, geo_type, latitude, longitude])
    return result

data_json = [
    {
        'C_ID' : '1',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    },
    {
        'C_ID' : '2',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    },
    {
        'C_ID' : '3',
        'Latlong' : {
            '__type' : 'GeoPoint',
            'latitude' : [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
        }
    }]

data = pd.read_json(json.dumps(data_json))
data['Common'] = data.apply(lambda x: extend_coordinates(coordinates=x['Latlong'].get('latitude', [None, None]),
                                                         c_id=x['C_ID'],
                                                  geo_type=x['Latlong'].get('__type', None)), axis=1)
data_ext = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(data['Common']), 
                        columns=['C_ID', '__type', 'latitude', 'longitude'])

# if data_ext dataframe is not enough, you can combine data to your desired output
data_ext['Latlong'] = data_ext.apply(lambda x: {'__type': x['__type'], 
                                                'latitude': x['latitude'], 
                                                'longitude': x['longitude']}, axis=1)
result = data_ext[['C_ID', 'Latlong']]
del data_ext, data
```

**UPDATE:**

To keep latitude and longitude in integer format you can do the following (assuming that all rows have non-null longitude and latitude and they correctly represent integer numbers):

```
data_ext['Latlong'] = data_ext.apply(lambda x: {'__type': x['__type'], 
                                                'latitude': int(x['latitude']), 
                                                'longitude': int(x['longitude'])}, axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you  please suggest the issue posted at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135246/how-to-convert-the-row-wise-data-of-dataframe-with-its-column-name-as-key-and-ro?noredirect=1#comment102657657_58135246

Comment: Hello @Eduard -According to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123611/10749561  
You have passed the data_json in the json format but I am having the dataframe how to implement it by dataframe

Comment: @P.D, hi! Take a look at 'data' variable. It's your initial dataframe. data_json is used by me to construct this dataframe. After constructing this dataframe data_json is never used.

Comment: According to your answer when I print the output of  data_ext['Latlong']  It is converting the values of latitude and longitude into string . I want the latitude and longitude in integer format.

Comment: Please suggest for the above comment

Comment: Kindly suggest on the question posted related to your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620173/converting-the-particular-subcolumn-of-the-dataframe-to-interger-from-the-string

Comment: Hello @P.D! You can look at update section. I had described the way you can get latitude and longitude in integer format.

Comment: Hi @Eduard -It is showing the error  ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: It means that you need to convert to float type instead of integer (according to your data from question). You should try to replace int() to float().