# Converting the particular subcolumn of the dataframe to interger from the string in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have used the code from the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123611/10749561 
From that answer I am facing the problem the output of the

```
data_ext['Latlong']
```

is converting the Latituide and Longitude integer numbers into string. I want the latitude and longitude in the interger format. How can I do this please suggest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split the sublist from the list and add the data in another list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115962/how-to-split-the-sublist-from-the-list-and-add-the-data-in-another-list)

Comment: Are you using the same data_json? If not, provide us your data sample, please.

Comment: @Eduard - In that answer when I used the https://stackoverflow.com/a/58123611/10749561    the updated one I am getting the error ValueError: ("invalid literal for int() with base 10:   .Kindly suggest

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)